# Search Textview which is created programmatic

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I'm adding TextViews programmatic using a for-loop and use setId(Int int) to set unique id for that perticular Textview.
But now I want to search textView on the basis of that id.
How can I search?

erorr occurd 'app stopped unexpectedly...' Here is my code.

```
public class Idtest extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
        tv=new TextView(this);

        tv.setText("Hello");
        ll.addView(tv);

        tv=new TextView(this);
        tv=(TextView)ll.getChildAt(1);

        setContentView(tv);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tv` is obviously `null` at the end (the `LinearLayout` only has one child, which is at index `0`), so you're basically calling `setContentView(null)` which results in an exception. It's not clear for me what you're trying to do (your code is pretty messed up).

Supposing you are trying to show multiple `TextView`s in a `LinearLayout`, here's my suggestion:

```
public class Idtest extends Activity {
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Hello " + i);
            mainLayout.addView(tv);
        }
    }
}
```

If, at any later point, you need one of the `TextView`s, do:

```
TextView tvX = mainLayout.getChildAt(X); // where X is between 0 and 9
```

---

Also, please note that creating layout from code is evil. If you can avoid it, please do. For example, if the number of `TextView`s is dynamic, then it's perfectly normal to create them from code (although you could inflate them). However, it's not advisable to also create the `LinearLayout` from code. You should have that in an XML. If it's possible for you to also have the `TextView`s in an XML, that would be even better.

Comment: Thanks, for code. But though I couldn't fetch perticular text box. Force to close app occured.  TextView tvX = (TextView) mainLayout.getChildAt(2); 
        setContentView(tvX); These Two line I have written.

Comment: Why do you `setContentView(tvX)`? It makes no sense, please explain what you are trying to do better.

Comment: I am just seeing that TextView on screen which I have fetched. To confirm that Selected TextView is correnct.

Comment: I don't mean to offend you, but please work on your English, it's really hard to understand what you want. If you just want to check that the correct `TextView` is selected you can use some other visual cue, such as `tvX.setText("I am selected!");`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I should improve my English I will. Thanks for grate advice And thanks for you answer. It's working.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option too...we have `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods. While adding a textview give a tag for it and whenever u want to do a search use getTag().

Comment: In setTag() as argument what should I pass?

Comment: any object, say string...for name textview u can set as nameTV.setTag("name");

Comment: But now how can I use getTag().

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are adding your TextView controls to some ViewGroup (e.g. LInearLayout)?

You can iterate through the ViewGroup child views using getChildCount() / getChildAt(index) and compare the child view id with the one you're searching for.

Comment: I have update my question...please check my code and tell me what is problem?